# Why doesn't this pause for input on the second cin when a long string of characters is passed to the first?

Tags: c++, cin

Below is some code for simple XOR encryption.  It prompts the user for a message, followed by a key, and it then encrypts the message with the key in 128-bit blocks.

When a short input (e.g.:  `test`) is entered as the message (the first `cin` call), the program pauses and awaits input from the key as expected.

If I enter a longer, more culturally rich message (e.g.: `Now is the winter of our discontent`), the program immediately returns from the `cin` call, failing to take input.  Any idea why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "string.h"
#include "assert.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

string getMessage();
string getPassphrase();
string setKey(string key);
string xorECB(string msg, string key);
char knownPlaintext(char ciphertext, char plaintext);

struct cipherblock
{
    char block[16];
};

int main(void)
{
    string plaintext = getMessage();
    string key = getPassphrase();

    string ciphertext = xorECB(plaintext, key);

    cout << plaintext.size() << endl;
    cout << key.size() << endl;
    cout << ciphertext.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}

string getMessage()
{
    cout << "Message: ";

    string msg;
    cin >> msg;
    cin.ignore();

    return msg;
}

string getPassphrase()
{
    cout << "Key: ";

    string key;
    cin >> key;
    cin.ignore();

    return setKey(key);
}

string setKey(string key)
/// Create 128-bit key from arbitrary-length ASCII passphrase.
{
    if (key.size() == 16)
        return key;

    if (key.size() < 16)
        key += key.substr(0, 16 - key.size());
    else
    {
        string keyxor = key.substr(16, key.size());
        key.erase(16, key.size() - 16);

        for (int i; i < keyxor.size(); i++)
            key[i] ^= keyxor[i];
    }

    return setKey(key); // keys shorter than 8 bytes need to be built recursively
}

string xorECB(string msg, string key)
/// XOR cipher operating in ECB mode, 128-bit block size
{
    assert(key.size() == 16);  // 16 bytes = 128 bits
    //for(int i = 0; i < msg.size(); i++)
        //msg[i] ^= key;

    for (int i = 0; i < msg.size() / sizeof(cipherblock); i++)
    {
        cipherblock *block = (cipherblock*)msg[0];

        for (int idx = 0; idx < key.size(); idx++)
            block->block[idx] ^= (char)key[idx];

        block++;
    }

    return msg;
}

char knownPlaintext(char ciphertext, char plaintext)
{
    return ciphertext ^ plaintext;
}
```

Any other comments and criticisms are also appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input operator `>>` *stops* at whitespace (i.e. the spaces between your words). If you want to get a whole line you should use e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Thanks!  Do I still need the `cin.ignore` call to flush the `\n` from the input buffer?

Comment: @blz No it's not needed, the "delimiter character" (normally newline) is extracted from the stream but not stored when using `std::getline`.

Answer (score 0):

cin would stop processing you input after the first whitespace it ecounters. So, you'll get only one word as input.